# I want to filter single value or multiple value in Laravel controller

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, search

I want to filter one value or multiple values in the Laravel controller

```
$news_paper_machine_ads = newsPaperMachineAds::join('news_paper_district', 'news_paper_district.idnews_paper_district', '=', 'news_paper_machine_ads.news_paper_district_id')
            ->join('news_paper_city', 'news_paper_city.idnews_paper_city', '=', 'news_paper_machine_ads.news_paper_city_id')
            ->join('news_paper_machine_field', 'news_paper_machine_field.idnews_paper_machine_field', '=', 'news_paper_machine_ads.news_paper_machine_field_id')
            ->where('district', 'LIKE', '%' . $district . '%')
            ->where('news_paper_city', 'LIKE', '%' . $city . '%')
            ->where('machine_field', 'LIKE', '%' . $machine_field .'%')
            ->get();

I want to filter this query past district value(only district data)
city = only city data
machine field = only machine field data
pass district and city = only district and city data
pass district and machine field= only district and machine field data
pass district, city and machine field = only district, city and machine field data
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $district = $request->district;
        $city = $request->city;
        $machine_field = $request->machine_field; 

$data_arry = array();

        if ($district != "Select") {
            $data_arry["district"] = $district;
        }

        if ($city != "Select") {
            $data_arry["city"] = $city;
        }

        if ($machine_field != "Select") {
            $data_arry["machine_field"] = $machine_field;
        }


        $news_paper_machine_ads = newsPaperMachineAds::join('news_paper_district', 'news_paper_district.idnews_paper_district', '=', 'news_paper_machine_ads.news_paper_district_id')
            ->join('news_paper_city', 'news_paper_city.idnews_paper_city', '=', 'news_paper_machine_ads.news_paper_city_id')
            ->join('news_paper_machine_field', 'news_paper_machine_field.idnews_paper_machine_field', '=', 'news_paper_machine_ads.news_paper_machine_field_id')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($data_arry) {

                if (isset($data_arry['district'])) {
                    $query->where('district', $data_arry['district']);
                }

                if (isset($data_arry['city'])) {
                    $query->where('news_paper_city', $data_arry['city']);
                }

                if (isset($data_arry['machine_field'])) {
                    $query->where('machine_field', $data_arry['machine_field']);
                }
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: This is the code working for me

Answer (score 0):

```
 $news_paper_machine_ads = newsPaperMachineAds::join('news_paper_district', 'news_paper_district.idnews_paper_district', '=', 'news_paper_machine_ads.news_paper_district_id')
            ->join('news_paper_city', 'news_paper_city.idnews_paper_city', '=', 'news_paper_machine_ads.news_paper_city_id')
            ->join('news_paper_machine_field', 'news_paper_machine_field.idnews_paper_machine_field', '=', 'news_paper_machine_ads.news_paper_machine_field_id')
            ->where(function($query) use($district,$city,$machine_field){
                if($district){
                    $query->where('district', 'LIKE', '%' . $district . '%');
                }
                if($city){
                    $query->where('news_paper_city', 'LIKE', '%' . $city . '%');
                }
                
                if($machine_field){
                    $query->where('machine_field', 'LIKE', '%' . $machine_field . '%');
                }
                

            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: Brother this query  work only past 3 values but I want to filter it past one value and many values filter  I want to filter this query past district value(only district data)
city = only city data
machine field = only machine field data
pass district and city = only district and city data
pass district and machine field= only district and machine field data
pass district, city and machine field = only district, city and machine field data

Comment: Suppose, the user can filter any value from the search filter. If the user filters only the district, then the other values will be blank. In this case this query 
 $query->where('district', 'LIKE', '%' . $district . '%');
execute. The same condition applies to others.

Comment: Brother, I have to filter 13 fields and select one field I want to search only one field select multiple fields I want to search various values >where(function($query) use($district,$city,$machine_field){ how can I add filter one value I want to add one value to use()  and I filter multiple values I want to add multiple values to use() how can I add it. Brother this is a multiple select tag advance search.

Answer (score 0):

use when and OrWhere query like this

```
    $news_paper_machine_ads = newsPaperMachineAds::join('news_paper_district', 'news_paper_district.idnews_paper_district', '=', 'news_paper_machine_ads.news_paper_district_id')
                ->join('news_paper_city', 'news_paper_city.idnews_paper_city', '=', 'news_paper_machine_ads.news_paper_city_id')
                ->join('news_paper_machine_field', 'news_paper_machine_field.idnews_paper_machine_field', '=', 'news_paper_machine_ads.news_paper_machine_field_id')
                ->when($district, function ($query) use ($district) {
                     return $query->orWhere('district', 'LIKE', '%' . $district . '%');
                })
                ->when($city, function ($query) use ($city) {
                     return $query->orWhere('news_paper_city', 'LIKE', '%' . $city . '%');
                })
                ->when($machine_field, function ($query) use ($machine_field) {
                     return $query->orWhere('machine_field', 'LIKE', '%' . $machine_field .'%');
                })->get();
```